# C# Loading an XML and setting variables

Tags: c#, xml, loading

I'm trying that when I start the program and click the Save button (like the ones in video games), it loads the variables from the save file. But when I try to load the variables, only the message box ("Save Loaded!") pops up and the XML doesn't overwrite my variables. Here is the code :

```
    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create("C:\\Save\\Save1.xml");
        while (xReader.Read())
        {
            if ((xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xReader.Name == "Variable"))
            {
                if (xReader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Loaded a save!");
                    Vars.zombies = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Variable","Zombies")));
                    Vars.infected = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Variable","Infected")));
                    Vars.wolfs = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Varaible","Wolfs")));
                }
            }
        }
```

This is when the program loads after saving. ^

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlTextWriter xWriter = new XmlTextWriter("C:\\Save\\Save1.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        xWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Variables");

        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Variable");
        xWriter.WriteAttributeString("Zombies",Vars.zombies.ToString());
        xWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Variable");
        xWriter.WriteAttributeString("Infected",Vars.infected.ToString());
        xWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Variable");
        xWriter.WriteAttributeString("Wolfs",Vars.wolfs.ToString());

        xWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xWriter.Close();
    }
```

This is the code, which saves the variables ^

```
public static double infected = 0;
public static double zombies = 0;
public static double wolfs = 0;
```

And finally the Variables in a separated class ^

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Saving works perfect but the program just doesn't load the variables.

Comment: Your static settings initialized to 0, and Convert method returns 0, because you pass to it `null` returned by `xReader.GetAttribute`. GetAttribute accepts namespace as second param, so you using it wrong. I believe you need find node `//Variables/Variable` (already done via `while` cycle) and then get its attributes with `node.GetAttribute("Infected")` etc. By the way you have a typo "Varaible" in last line of load method.

Comment: Hmm , my heads everywhere right now since ive been trying to fix it for a while now , Can you give a bit more detail on what I should change ?

Comment: @elgonzo `Convert.ToDouble` will _not_ throw an exception. "A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to the number in value, or 0 (zero) if value is null." - according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Tommi, you are right, ToDouble does not throw if a `null` reference is passed.. Darn, apparently i can't read MSDN documentation anymore - what happened to me?... :)

Comment: why not use settings file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code for a test.

```
Vars.zombies = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Zombies")));
Vars.infected = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Infected")));
Vars.wolfs = (Convert.ToDouble(xReader.GetAttribute("Wolfs")));
```

Inside GetAttributes, you just need to pass the name of the attribute whose value you're trying to retrieve. The 2nd optional parameter takes the namespace URI of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you a very naive approach, which is ok for a few variables. Please consider to use some powerful feature like `DataContractSerializer` if you need to store more data.

First of all I would start to change from attributes to values, your current implementation requires more difficult search in XML file.

```
 private static void Save()
    {
        var xWriter = new XmlTextWriter("Save1.xml", Encoding.UTF8);
        xWriter.WriteStartDocument();
        xWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xWriter.WriteStartElement("Variables");

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Zombies");
            xWriter.WriteValue(Vars.zombies);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Infected");
            xWriter.WriteValue(Vars.infected);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();

            xWriter.WriteStartElement("Wolfs");
            xWriter.WriteValue(Vars.wolfs);
            xWriter.WriteEndElement();

        xWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xWriter.Close();
    }
```

Here I used WriteValue instead of WriteAttributeString. This gives us xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Variables>
  <Zombies>1</Zombies>
  <Infected>1</Infected>
  <Wolfs>1</Wolfs>
</Variables>
```

Now, we use direct value reading to get data:

```
private static void Read()
        {
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create("Save1.xml");
            while (xReader.Read())
            {
                if (xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    switch (xReader.Name)
                    {
                        case "Zombies":
                            Vars.zombies = xReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                        break;
                        case "Infected":
                            Vars.infected = xReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                        break;
                        case "Wolfs":
                            Vars.wolfs = xReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is full demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rQUsD